# Customise TextInputEditText with a CountryCode Picker

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, mobile-country-code

Hi I want to make edit text look like this                 [image]

I have tried adding country picker in textinputlayout, but it never draws view as shown in layout editor

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/x60"
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
                android:layout_width="@dimen/x40"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:ccp_defaultNameCode="US"
                app:ccp_defaultLanguage="ENGLISH"
                app:ccp_arrowColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:ccp_textGravity="RIGHT"/>
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="Phone Number"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/x16"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:id="@+id/et_phone"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone_outline"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Country picker goes below the textinputlayout always, even I set orientation to horizontal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Need to create a background

**1- Create a drawable resource File and name it whatever you want**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"   >
    <solid
        android:color="#F8F8F8" >
    </solid>

    <corners
        android:radius="10dp"   >
    </corners>

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#C2C2C3"/>

</shape>
```

2- Now Create Download Pakistan's Flag Image from [Here](https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/pakistan/flag-800.png) and name it **flag_pk**

3- Import Vector Asset **call Icon** and name it to **tmep_call**

4- Now copy-paste the code given below into the layout where you need your editText

**Now comes the real part**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/temp_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconPhone"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/temp_call" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_bold"
                android:text="Phone Number"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:src="@mipmap/flag_pk" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_bold"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="+92"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_bold"
                    android:hint="12345678900"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**END result will look like this**

**5: NOTE:: YOU NEED TO REPLACE THE TEXT "+92" WITH YOUR CODE PICKER"**

[image]

Comment: I want it with textinputLayout and TextInputEditText. not with linear layouts or something else. and the flag is not simple image its a country picker

Comment: replace the image with country picker then!

Comment: just keep the width and heights same

Comment: and is it necessary to use TextInputEditText?

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:orientation="vertical"` to `android:orientation="horizontal"`